# Accessing Request Headers in React Native Expo WebView

Tags: javascript, react-native, cookies, webview, expo

I am currently working on a React Native project using Expo, and I'm facing challenges with the **react-native-webview** package. Specifically, I need to access the request headers before the request is initiated.

I'm particularly interested in obtaining the **`Cookie`** and a custom header, let's call it
**`custom-header-key`**, from the request headers made by the browser, not the headers set by my application.

Despite my efforts, including various approaches and injecting JavaScript code, I have not been successful in obtaining these headers.

If anyone has experience or insights into how to access the request headers made by the browser in a React Native Expo WebView, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Any help or suggestions would be highly valued.

Thank you in advance!